# Print divisors in order using theta(n) efficiency

Tags: c++, algorithm

I'm struggling to implement this correctly.  I want to create a function that determines all of the divisors of the user input `userNum` and outputs them to the user.  When `userNum` = 16 i'm getting the output 1 16 2 8.  I didn't expect the order to be correct, but i'm missing 4 and am struggling to figure out why.  Any thoughts?  I'm trying to do this in theta(sqrt(num)) efficiency.

```
void PrintDivisors(int num);

int main()
{
    int userNum;

    //Request user number

    cout << "Please input a positive integer >=2:" << endl;
    cin >> userNum;

    PrintDivisors(userNum);

    return 0;
}

void PrintDivisors(int num)
{
    int divisorCounter;

    for (divisorCounter = 1; divisorCounter < sqrt(num); divisorCounter++)
    {
        if (num % divisorCounter == 0 && num / divisorCounter != divisorCounter)
            cout << divisorCounter << endl << num / divisorCounter << endl;
        else if (num % divisorCounter == 0 && num / divisorCounter == divisorCounter)
            cout << divisorCounter << endl;
    }
}
```

**Update: I have all the numbers printing, but still trying to determine how to print them in order while remaining within theta sqrt(n) efficiency**

Comment: divisorCounter < sqrt(num)

Comment: @huck_cussler i'm sorry i'm not following.  That's what I have in my for loop no?

Comment: Yeah, that's your stopping condition for the loop.  Think about the implications of that condition when num is 16.

Comment: OH!  Thank you! @huck_cussler      Now I just need to get them in order, which is another animal

Answer (score 2):

1. Change loop termination condition operation to `<=`, now you will observe `4`.
2. Get rid of `sqrt` function call. Better use this loop

   ```
   for (divisorCounter = 1; divisorCounter * divisorCounter <= num; divisorCounter++)
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to check your edge conditions carefully.

1. What is `sqrt(num)`?
2. What is the largest `divisorCounter` that will pass the test in the `for` loop?
3. Would `4` pass the test?

I think if you look carefully at that line with these three questions in mind you will squash the bug.

Comment: I've got it functioning properly as far as the divisors.  Struggling to output them in the proper order.  I'm not sure it can be done with only one for loop

Comment: Print the lower divisor in the for loop, and (if the resulting larger divisor is not the same - i.e., not square root), prepend the larger divisor onto a running string.  For 16, print 1, prepend 16 onto (initially empty) string. Print 2, prepend 8.  Print 4, don't prepend the other 4.  No second loop, just print the collected string (8 16).

That gets rid of a 2nd for loop.  Personally, I think collecting the numbers in an array and printing them in reverse (2nd loop) seems less expensive,and is still O(sqrt n).

Answer (score 0):

**For making it run in sqrt(n) time complexity:**

For any n = a X b. either a<=sqrt(n) or b<=sqrt(n). 
So if you can find all divisors in range [1,sqrt(n)] you can find other divisors greater than sqrt(n)

You can use a for loop to traverse numbers in range 1 to sqrt(n) and find all the divisors less than sqrt(n), which at the same time you can also use to find other numbers greater than(or equal to) sqrt(n).

Suppose a number i < sqrt(n) is divisor or n. In that case the number k = n/i will also be divisor of n. But bigger than sqrt(n).

**For printing numbers in sorted order:**

During finding divisors in range [1,sqrt(n)] print only divisor in range [1,sqrt(n)] You can use an array/vector to store numbers in range [sqrt(n),n] and print them after the for loop ends. Here is a sample code

```
vector<int> otherNums;
for(i=1;i*i<n;i++) {
    if(num%i==0){
        cout<<i<<endl;
        otherNums.push_back(n/i);
    } 
}
if(i*i == n) otherNums.push_back(i);
for(i=(int)v.size() - 1 ;i>=0;i--) 
    cout<<otherNums[i]<<endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I ended up using, which saves space complexity too. I was struggling to think of effective ways to loop over the solution in ascending order, but this one runs very fast and is nicer than appending to a vector or array or some weird string concatenation.

```
void printDivisors(int num)
{
  for (int k = 1; k*k < num; k++)
  {
      if (num % k == 0)
          cout << k << " ";
  }

  for (int d = sqrt(num); d >= 1; d--)
  {
      if (num % d == 0)
          cout << num / d << " ";
  }

  cout << endl;
}
```